# Submit form is not working in asp

Tags: asp-classic

While sending an email at website I am facing an issue when submitting the form. The form can be found at the following location.

http://www.someone.com/medicalights/contact.htm

I am using SMTPsvg.Mailer object to send the email. Is this object is supported on the server and If yes, can we use the localhost in the remote host property. I've also tried CDONTS.New | MailCDO.Message but these are also not working fine. Please ask the support department of the hosting company about this issue.

The following code is using to send the email.

Set Mailer = Server.CreateObject("SMTPsvg.Mailer")

```
Mailer.RemoteHost = "localhost" 
Mailer.ReturnReceipt = false
Mailer.ConfirmRead = false
Mailer.Priority = 1
Mailer.Urgent = false
Mailer.Timeout = 30

Mailer.FromName = "someone.com"
Mailer.FromAddress = "info@someone.com"
Mailer.AddRecipient "que33@gmail.com", "que33@gmail.com"
Mailer.Subject = "CONTACT US Request"
Mailer.BodyText = Body

SendMail = Mailer.SendMail
```

i am using same code for another website its working perfect but this one is not and both website's contact form sending email to same address.

Comment: Have you tried CDOSYS?  SMTPsvg.Mailer is a third party component - it isn't installed on a windows server by default.  CDONTS was standard on NT servers, but it has now been replaced by CDOSYS

Answer (score 0):

The link to your form doesn't work. I would like to see the HTML of your form, as well as your ASP code that reads the submitted data. I also concur with John's recommendation you use CDOSYS code for sending mail. THAT is probably your problem. Here is the function I created for my CMS to use whenever a page needs to send an email:

```
<%
function email(s_from,s_reply_to,s_recipients,s_bcc,s_subject,s_msg,s_type,s_msg_error_add,s_remote_host)

    if (s_msg_error_add<>"") then s_msg_error_add = "<hr>" & vbCrLf & s_msg_error_add
    if (s_remote_host="default") then s_remote_host = application("s_mail_server")
    if (s_remote_host="") then s_remote_host = "localhost"
    s_remote_host=lcase(s_remote_host)

    's_recipients looks like "Scott <scott@domain.net>; Sue <andy@domain.net>" etc

    s_from = replace(s_from,","," ",1,-1,1)
    s_from = replace(s_from,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
    s_from = replace(s_from,"[","<",1,-1,1)
    s_from = replace(s_from,"]",">",1,-1,1)

    if (s_reply_to<>"") then
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,","," ",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"[","<",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"]",">",1,-1,1)
    end if

    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,",",";",1,-1,1)
    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"[","<",1,-1,1)
    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"]",">",1,-1,1)

    if (s_bcc<>"") then 
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,","," ",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"[","<",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"]",">",1,-1,1)
    end if

    err.clear

    Dim MailerConfig
    Dim Mailer
    Dim strRet
    dim sch

    strRet = ""
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

    Set MailerConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set Mailer = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    With MailerConfig.Fields
        '.Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 'send using port - if err then this is really "SendUsingMethod"
        '.Item(sch & "sendusingmethod") = 2 'send using port - if err then this is really "SendUsingMethod"
        .Item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 900
        '.Item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 'use basic (clear-text) authentication
        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = s_remote_host
        '.Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 25
        '.Item(sch & "sendusername") = SMAUTHUSER
        '.Item(sch & "sendpassword") = SMAUTHPASS
        .Update
    End With
    Mailer.Configuration = MailerConfig

    'Mailer.Fields(cdoImportance) = 1
    'Mailer.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MSMail-Priority") = 1
    'Mailer.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Mailer") = ""
    'Mailer.Fields.Update

    '-- Set the Mail Properties

    'on error resume next

    Mailer.From = s_from
    Mailer.To = s_recipients
    if (s_reply_to<>"" and s_reply_to<>"na") then Mailer.ReplyTo = s_reply_to

    b_redirect=false

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 72, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    if (s_bcc<>"" AND s_bcc<>"na" AND s_bcc<>"n/a") then Mailer.BCC = s_bcc

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 79, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    Mailer.Subject = s_subject

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 86, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    if (s_type="html") then
        Mailer.AutoGenerateTextBody = True
        s_msg = replace(s_msg,vbCrLf,"<br>",1,-1,1)
    else
        Mailer.AutoGenerateTextBody = False         
    end if

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 103, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    Mailer.MimeFormatted = False

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 110, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    if (s_type = "text") then
        Mailer.TextBody = fn_dirty(s_msg)
    else
        's_msg_html = replace(s_msg,vbCrLf,"<br>",1,-1,1)
        s_msg_html = s_msg
        Mailer.HTMLBody = fn_dirty(s_msg_html)
    end if

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 123, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    '-- Fire off the email message

    Mailer.Send

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        Select Case err.Number
            Case -2147220973
                strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Server Not Found" & vbCrLf & " Error: " & err.Number & " - " &  err.Description
            Case -2147220975
                strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Server Authentication Failed" & vbCrLf & " Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
            Case Else
                strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
        End Select

        msg = "<br>Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp: " & strRet & "<br><br>"

        msg = msg & "remote host = " & s_remote_host & "<br>"
        s_from = replace(s_from,"<","[",1,-1,1)
        s_from = replace(s_from,">","]",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"<","]",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,">","[",1,-1,1)
        s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"<","[",1,-1,1)
        s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,">","]",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"<","[",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,">","]",1,-1,1)

        msg = msg & "from = " & s_from & "<br>"
        msg = msg & "to = " & s_recipients & "<br>"
        msg = msg & "subject = " & s_subject & "<br>"
        msg = msg & "recipients = " & s_recipients & "<br><br>"

        if (s_type = "text") then
            msg = msg & s_msg
        else
            msg = msg & s_msg_html
        end if
        msg = msg & "<br>"      
        msg = msg & s_msg_error_add
        session("msg") = msg
        Set Mailer = Nothing
        set MailerConfig = nothing

        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    Set Mailer = Nothing
    set MailerConfig = nothing

    email = true

end function

Function fn_dirty(FixWhat)
    if (isnull(FixWhat) or FixWhat="") then
        FixWhat=""
    else
        FixWhat=trim(FixWhat)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<ahref","<a href",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<spanclass","<span class",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#146;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&apos;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"%27","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#39;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#146;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#47;","/",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"''''","'''",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#34;",chr(34),1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"%22",chr(34),1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(13) & chr(10),"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"title=","alt=",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"src=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"src=" & chr(34) & "/images","src=" & chr(34) & "images",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"background=" & chr(34) & chr(32),"background=" & chr(34) & chr(34) & chr(32),1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"x=" & chr(34) & chr(32)," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&lt;","<",1,-1,1)      
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&gt;",">",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"//<![CDATA[","",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"//]]","",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TABLE","<table",1,-1,1)       
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TBODY>","<tbody>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TR","<tr",1,-1,1)             
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<TD","<td",1,-1,1) 
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"</TR>","</tr>",1,-1,1)             
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"</TD>","</td>",1,-1,1) 

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<html><br>","<html>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<head><br>","<head>",1,-1,1)       
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<body><br>","<body>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><tbody>","<tbody>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<tbody><br>","<tbody>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><tr>","<tr>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<tr><br>","<tr>",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br><td","<td",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"<br></html>","</html>",1,-1,1)
    end if
    fn_dirty=FixWhat
End Function
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be this line..

```
Mailer.RemoteHost = "localhost"
```

If localhost is not configured to send/relay for that user/domain it will fail without giving any indication. If you have a mail server already configured for youu site, try setting that as the RemoteHost. You can use alias.domain or IP number.